# How to send test push notification with custom data from firebase console?

Tags: react-native, push-notification

How do we send a test push notification to my android emulator with custom data? I have FCM Token and it should directly come up on my emulator only... I don't want to send a notification to all the app users.

Is there any way to do this from firebase cloud messageing so, I can test with my data.

Comment: I think Push Notification work only on real devices.

Comment: yes, I got that... I was trying if anyway for doing this because sometimes my states not updating and the output is showing undefined. This is my main concern >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55710653/react-native-push-notification-data-showing-undefined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Sure you can test it through printing the device token

```
  FCM.getFCMToken().then(token => {
   console.log(token)
  });
```

Then take the token and go to the cloud messaging section and you just set the FCM token in test message like the picture below:

[image]

**Update**

the new Firebase interface does not provides a direct way to test cloud messaging with data at the moment. However you have two options: either you create a certain subject and subscribe to it like the following code

```
  FCM.subscribeToTopic("/topics/testTopic");
```

and then in the target section you can target topic `testTopic` (This may require time to confirm a new subject)

Or you can do this programming using Firebase admin, you can follow this tutorial: 
https://medium.com/android-school/test-fcm-notification-with-postman-f91ba08aacc3

Hopefully this answer your question

Comment: Yes that will helpfull but i need to pass custom data too with notification.

Comment: I just update my answer and hope this will help you better @RahulMishra

Comment: Just for clarification creating a topic may take a bit as stated in the console "There is a delay of up to one day between new topic creation and when it becomes available as a target." In case someone is wondering why the topic not showing up, after subscribing.

Comment: That's crazy that you can't test custom data anymore.... 2023 and still not possible it seems :(